# Cannot change src of image with Javascript in some versions of Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

Never could have imagined that chrome would have been the browser giving me grief, but the slideshow for our new website does not function properly in some versions of Chrome.

The error occurs here:

```
"mainPicture.src = \''.$directory.$current_pic.'\'; setMarkerPos('.$i.')"
```

Claiming that I can't modify mainPicture, an id that doesn't exist.
Obviously, other browsers don't have a problem seeing this object.

All help is much appreciated!

.

You can find the page [here](http://www.northviewhigh.com/index/frontpage/slideshow/FrontPageSlideshow.php).

Source code:

```
<?php 
/********************************************************************
 *                GATHER IMAGES FROM IMAGE DIRECTORY                *
 ********************************************************************/

// Define directory where images are stored
$directory = "../../images/slideshow/";

// Create blank array to store image names
$pic_array = array("");
$num_pics;

// Create number to define position of images in array
$counter = 0;

// Gather pictures from image directory
if(is_dir($directory))
{   
    // Open directory to view files
    if($dh = opendir($directory))
    {   
        // Continue while still files to view
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {   
            // Stop if picture limit of 6 reached
            if($counter == 6)
                break;

            // Gather if object found is file or directory
            $file_check = filetype($directory.$file);

            // If object is a file, add it to the slideshow
            if ($file_check == "file")
            {
                $extension = substr($file, strpos($file, "."));

                if ($extension == ".png" || $extension == ".jpg")
                {
                    $pic_array[$counter] = $file;
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

// Determine number of pics gathered
$num_pics = count($pic_array);
?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="scripts/slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<?php
/********************************************************************
 *                  CONTROL BEHAVIORS OF SLIDESHOW                  *
 ********************************************************************/
?>
<!-- Begin script to control slideshow -->
<script type = "text/javascript">
var thumbTop    = 450; // starting value of thumb.style.top (make sure multiple of increment)
var highestTop  = 342; // highest point mask can be on screen ,-, (make sure multiple of increment)
var lowestTop   = 450; // lowest point mask can be on screen ,_, (make sure multiple of increment)
var delay = 2;      // speed in which slide up and down methods are called
var increment = 5;  // value that thumbTop increments with each method call
var intervalUp;     // interval for thumb upward movements 
var intervalDown;   // interval for thumb downward movements

function startThumbSlideUp()
{
    window.clearInterval(intervalDown);
    intervalUp = window.setInterval(thumbSlideUp,delay);
}

function startThumbSlideDown()
{
    window.clearInterval(intervalUp);
    intervalDown = window.setInterval(thumbSlideDown,delay);
}

function thumbSlideUp()
{
    thumbTop -= increment;

    if (thumbTop <= highestTop)
    {
        thumbTop = highestTop;
        window.clearInterval(intervalUp);
    }
    else
        thumbMask.style.top = thumbTop;
}

function thumbSlideDown()
{
    // Added to fix issue where images would start from too large a height
    if (thumbTop <= highestTop)
        thumbTop = highestTop;

    thumbTop += increment;

    if (thumbTop >= lowestTop)
    {
        thumbTop = lowestTop;
        window.clearInterval(intervalDown);
    }
    else
        thumbMask.style.top = thumbTop;
}

// Move marker above image <pos>
function setMarkerPos(pos)
{
    marker.style.left = 600 - (66 * (pos)) + 19;
}

</script>
</head>

<?php
/********************************************************************
 *                        DISPLAY SLIDESHOW                         *
 ********************************************************************/

// Start body and make images unhighlightable
echo '<body onselectstart="return false" style="margin: 0px;">';

// Create base value to increment horizontal position of thumbnails
$curr_thumb_left = 595; // (ignore this comment) 660<width of image> - 66<width of thumb> - 10<space between side> // 660

// Create and display main (large) image and image thumbnails
echo '<div id="mask" onmouseout = "startThumbSlideDown()" onmouseover = "startThumbSlideUp();">
';
echo '<img src = "'.$directory.$pic_array[0].'" id = "mainPicture" height = "420" width = "660" style = "z-index: -1; position:absolute;"/>
';
echo '<div id="thumbMask" height="66" width="660" style="z-index: 1; top: 450px; position: absolute;">
';
echo '<img id="marker" src="images/marker.png" height="10" width="10" style="z-index: 2; top: 0px; position: absolute;" onload="setMarkerPos(0);"/>';

// Search through image array, then assign names to and display thumbnails
for ($i=0; $i < $num_pics; $i++)
{
    // Point to pic in array
    $current_pic = $pic_array[$i];

    // Create and display image thumbnails
    if ($current_pic !== "")
    {       
        echo '<img src = "'.$directory.$current_pic.'" id = "thumb'.$i.'" height = "50" width = "50" style = "left:'.$curr_thumb_left.'px; top: 10px; border: 3px white solid; position: absolute;" onclick = "mainPicture.src = \''.$directory.$current_pic.'\'; setMarkerPos('.$i.')"/>
        ';

        // Move left value to the left [50px width + (3px padding * 2 sides) + 10px space between = 66px]
        $curr_thumb_left -= 66;
    }
}

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: Chrome has great Developer tools where you can type in arbitrary javascript and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome doesn't make image elements available by just their "id" value; you have to use `document.getElementById("mainPicture")` to get a reference to the DOM element.  That'll work in all browsers anyway, so it's safe to just code it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to alter the src of mainPicture as though it were a global variable:

```
mainPicture.src = '.....';
```

Try referencing mainPicture by its `id` instead:

```
document.getElementById('mainPicture').src = '......';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually setting what mainPicture is, other browsers must be guessing whereas Chrome is doing what it should. Change:

```
    echo '<img src = "'.$directory.$current_pic.'" id = "thumb'.$i.'" height = "50" width = "50" style = "left:'.$curr_thumb_left.'px; top: 10px; border: 3px white solid; position: absolute;" onclick = "mainPicture.src = \''.$directory.$current_pic.'\'; setMarkerPos('.$i.')"/>
```

to

```
    echo '<img src = "'.$directory.$current_pic.'" id = "thumb'.$i.'" height = "50" width = "50" style = "left:'.$curr_thumb_left.'px; top: 10px; border: 3px white solid; position: absolute;" onclick = "document.getElementById('mainPicture').src = \''.$directory.$current_pic.'\'; setMarkerPos('.$i.')"/>
```